# WPF custom control has different foregound in designer and running mode

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

In a new WpfApp1, I am adding a new custom control (WPF) name CustomButton.
In its static constructor I set the default foreground to be yellow.
In MainWindow.xaml I am adding a CostomButton.

In the designer its foreground is yellow (correct).
Running the application, the foreground is black (wrong).

Any ideas why this happen?

CustomButton.cs:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    static CustomButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomButton)));

        CustomButton.ForegroundProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Yellow));
    }
}
```

Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomButton}">
                <Button
                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    Content="asdf 01">
                </Button>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <local:CustomButton Width="200" Height="100"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't know if it will work or not, but there's a good chance that your static constructor never ran. Add a dummy static Init() method and call it on app start. Usually static constructors run when something is called statically the first time.

Comment: TyCobb, I added a 3d line in the static constructor:
    MessageBox.Show("hello");
and it shows running in both design and running mode, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

The default Foreground of the custom Button seems to be overwritten by an application-wide Style.

Instead of changing the default Foreground, add a Setter to the control's default Style:

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
    ...
</Style>
```